# How to pre-populate fields when creating a new record?

Tags: custom-object, process-builder, automation, process-automation

I have a custom parent object A and a child object B.

When I create a new record from the child object B via the related list, only the parent lookup field is defaulted and filled in.

When I hit create new in the related list, I need to add more fields to be auto filled in.

Is there an appropriate solution to such issue?

Please advise if there is a way by using the process builder or some other means of automation processes?

Comment: Lightning or Classic?

Comment: Classic version

Comment: if the fields are not mandatory, you can use a workflow rule, a Process builder and so on. After, the user should edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In **lightning**: you can do that using [Set Predefined Field Values for Quick Action Fields](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=predefined_field_values.htm&type=5).  Here you predefine values for the new record created in quick action attributes and thus they gets prepopulated when you click the quick action button.

In **Classic** : In classic you can use [URL hacking](https://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-url-hacking-tutorial/) : Here you pass the FieldID and its value in URL params and they get set in the corresponding fields accordingly.

Src : https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=predefined_field_values.htm&type=5

Src : https://www.salesforceben.com/salesforce-url-hacking-tutorial/