# salesforce Pre fill value in create page

Tags: visualforce, controller, pagereference, standardcontroller, edit

Is it possible that pre fill value on the create page

example:

```
public PageReference Create() { 
Contact tmp = new Contact (); 
tmp.Name    ='test123'; 
return new apexPages.StandardController(tmp).edit(); 
}
```

Comment: Please check this post https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/240676/how-to-pre-populate-fields-when-creating-a-new-record.

Comment: if im using lighting, there are no url hacking? or any way to preset value by coding?

Comment: @cheuklaw Have you tried using Predefined Field Values for Quick Action Fields and calling your component?

Answer (score 2):

There are few ways you can pre-defined the fields i create form:-

1. By using the Quick Action of type create a record. It Allows you to pre-defined the field values for the field available on the base object of the action. Read here for an working example:- [REPLACING URL HACKS WITH PRE-DEFINED ACTIONS IN LIGHTNING EXPERIENCE](https://salesforcediaries.com/2019/05/28/replacing-url-hacks-with-pre-defined-actions-in-lightning-experience/)
2. If you are dealing with some complex scenarios, You can choose the Lightning Aura Component route and use [force:createRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:createRecord) to create a new record form with pre-defined values. It has an attribute called **defaultFieldValues** which gives you an ability to set the field values dynamically.
3. You can go for Visualforce page also. Use the standardController and get the current record in constructor of the extension and manipulate the field values with your desired value. Check a sample example here:- [Prepopulate Lookup Field in Standard Controller Visualforce Page](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005gy9QAA)

Comment: Option 2 is great for me much thanks!!

Comment: You can accept the answer if it has served the purpose.